# Setting asyncio.Future's value in a callback from different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety, python-asyncio

I have a library that gives me an option to schedule a callback when an external job finishes. Is it safe to use this callback for `Future.set_result()`? If not, what is the proper way to achieve this? Future's documentation says that its methods are not thread safe, so I assume there might be a problem with this.

My goal is to use OpenCL events from PyOpenCL as awaitable objects in asyncio code. I was thinking about a helper function like this:

```
def wrap_opencl_event(event):
    f = asyncio.Future()
    event.set_callback(pyopencl.command_execution_status.COMPLETE, lambda x: f.set_result(None))
    return f
```

and using it this way:

```
async def do_slow_stuff():
    ev1 = pyopencl.enqueue_something()
    ev2 = pyopencl.enqueue_something_else(wait_for=[ev1])
    await wrap_opencl_event(ev2)
    process_results()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading the documentation a bit more thoroughly it seems that the future's value should be set in a callback scheduled with the event loop:

```
def wrap_opencl_event(event):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    f = loop.create_future()
    event.set_callback(pyopencl.command_execution_status.COMPLETE,
                       lambda status: loop.call_soon_threadsafe(f.set_result, None))
    return f
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use concurrent.futures and to wrap the future

```
import asyncio.futures, concurrent.futures
async def func_returning_future(loop):
    fut = concurrent.futures.Future()
    # Pass off to your other thread somehow
    # and return a wrapped future for asyncio
    return asyncio.futures.wrap_future(fut, loop = loop)
```

Or since the function is an async def you could even await it within the loop, replacing the last line with

```
    await asyncio.futures.wrap_future(fut, loop = loop)
```

Comment: This seems clean. Is it safe and performant? The concurrent documentation says not to construct Future directly except in unit tests, but I have no idea why that is.

Comment: On my side it worked. But the `await` take too much time to receive the result. The time between the feature is done and the await is achieved varies between 1 and 100 ms, which is too long.. Do you have the same issue ?